# How do I group Quick Launch icons in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista

My quick launch task bar has about 30 icons and is pretty unmanegable.

What I would like is to create Quick Launch groups, so I can move my mouse over the "Design Group" icon and a pop-up/menu will appear that shows my icons for Illustrator, Photoshop, etc...

I can *almost* get there by linking to a folder and having my Design icons in there, but I have to click on the icon.

Can anyone recommend anything here?

Comment: Can only think about Windows 7 like jumplists to achieve this. | (What about simply using Launchy?)

Comment: Okay can't edit my first comment: What about using the Win+ typing? Just add quick launch to your indexed places and you can launch the "not-so-important" files. OR move your unused stuff to the back, and move the quick launch to show an arrow which pop ups a menu.

Comment: I think you just described the Start Menu, which I don't think Quick Launch was designed to entirely replace. (and yes, in fact I am  wondering what kind of workflow would warrant that many quick launches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickLaunch does as you say with a folder, BUT you can do a New Toolbar that has the behavior you want.

It will still be located on the taskbar but can stay organized and it will cascade open. I do this for a way to managed web shortcuts I can use in any browser. Drag them to the folder. Subfolders within folders work too and they are your own secondary QuickLaunch toolbar